# Making email id as "required" in Facebook login

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have integrated *Facebook* login with my app however if user clicks on "Edit permissions" while logging in, they can uncheck email address and then i don't get their email address. How can i make it **mandatory** or as Facebook says **"required"**

I have seen in many apps that the email is required field and you can't uncheck it. Here is an image for the same

[image]

Comment: Please mention a reason if you are down voting.

Answer (score 0):

You can´t. It is completely up to the user to select extended permissions. You can only check if he deselected a specific one after authorizing: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/user/permissions#Reading

Comment: Then how do other apps have it as "required"?

Comment: they may still not have been upgraded to v2.0, i believe it was possible to force it in lower versions. the automated upgrade process may still go on, sooner or later all apps will be v2.0 minimum.